# Can I use Bootstrap 4 Beta on my production sites?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Can anyone advise me, can I use `Bootstrap 4 Beta 3` on my production sites?

[getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bootstrap 4 Beta 3 is the last release before the final release.

No breaking changes will be introduced in the final release.

Also, there are only a few minor bugs in Bootstrap 4 Beta 3 most of which have already been fixed in the development branch. Bootstrap 4.0 final is expected to come out within a few weeks. (possibly within 4-6 weeks from now).

Here's the link to the official blog post confirming that there will be no breaking changes anymore:

https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/12/28/bootstrap-4-beta-3/

Comment: How do you think, will get an issue when will upgrade `Bootstrap 4 Beta 3` to `Bootstrap 4 final` ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. As I said, Bootstrap 4 final will be just a few minor bug fixes. So, if you use `Bootstrap 4 Beta 3` and everything looks fine then it will just the same when you upgrade to Bootstrap 4 final. You will NOT have anything breaking the layout or breaking anything else.

Comment: well thank you very much for helping. :)